# copy behavior in vector constructed with a initializer list

Tags: c++, vector

I realize that initializing a vector with a `initializer_list` relying on the copy constructor instead of the move constructor. For example, the following code print `copy`

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A(const string& ss): s(ss) {}
    A(A&& other) {
        cout << "move" << endl; 
        s = std::move(other.s); 
    }
    A(const A& other) {
        cout << "copy" << endl; 
        s = other.s; 
    }
    A& operator=(const A& other) {
        cout << "copy =" << endl;
        s = other.s;
        return *this; 
    }
    A& operator=(A&& other) {
        cout << "move =" << endl;
        s = std::move(other.s);
        return *this; 
    }
private:
    string s;
};

int main() {
    vector<A> as = vector{
        A("abc"),
    };
}
```

This requires the template type have the copy constroctor. Is there a way to achieve the same but using the move constructor only? I know that `push_back` with an `rvalue` invokes the move constructor(e.g. the code below). But it could be lengthy if the vector is initialized with multiple elements.

```cpp
int main() {
    vector<A> as;
    as.push_back(A("abc"));
}
// output "move"
```

Comment: FYI, `as.push_back(A("abc"));` should be replaced with `as.emplace_back("abc");` instead to making a temporary `A` at all.

Comment: Have you try  `std::forward`?

Comment: @Mr.Chip `std::forward` is only useful when handling forwarding references

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` makes *copies* of the values that are given to it.  And those copies are `const`, so the `vector` can't even *move* them if it wanted to.  So, initializing/assigning a `vector` using a *braced-init-list* will always perform a copy operation, never a move operation.

Even if you changed the code to use an `A[]` array as input instead, passing iterators for the array into the `vector` constructor, the `vector` will still *copy* the values from the array, not *move* them.

What you could do, though, is use [`std::vector::emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) instead:

```cpp
int main() {
    A ghi("ghi");
    vector<A> as;
    as.emplace(as.end(), "abc", A("def"), std::move(ghi), ...);
}
```

**UPDATE**: Or, if you have a lot of values to put into the `vector`, and you don't want to hard-code the list as this is doing, then you can use the [`std::move()` algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) (not to be confused with the [`std::move()` type cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)), eg:

```cpp
int main() {
    A items[] = {"abc", "def", "ghi", ...};
    // or whatever sequence you want to store the values in, 
    // as long as it supports iterators...

    vector<A> as;
    as.reserve(std::size(items));
    std::move(std::begin(items), std::end(items), std::back_inserter(as));
}
```

Which is basically just a wrapper for a `std::vector::push_back()` loop:

```cpp
vector<A> as;
as.reserve(std::size(items));
for(auto &val : items) {
    as.push_back(std::move(val));
}
```

**UPDATE:** Alternatively, you can use *move iterators* with  the `vector` constructor:

```cpp
vector<A> as(
    std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(items)),
    std::make_move_iterator(std::end(items))
);
```